# Why does Shushan Purim exist? Why don't we follow the principle of "rov"?

Tags: purim, cities, shushan-purim

(follow up question to [scimonster](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5151/scimonster)'s [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69245/why-do-we-need-a-separate-celebration-for-shushan-purim-in-walled-cities))

Shushan Purim was enacted because Jews in walled cities stopped fighting on the 15th and thus that's when they celebrated, opposed to the rest of Klal Yisrael who celebrated on the 14th (see [Beis Yosef, Orach Chaim 688:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef%2C_Orach_Chaim.688.3.1?lang=bi&with=Halakhah&lang2=bi)).

My question is: **why don't we follow *rov*** (majority)?

I understand that people in walled cities were still fighting on the 14th, but since the majority of Jews WEREN'T and were instead celebrating, shouldn't that majority be enough to *kovea*(establish) that Purim be on the 14th for everyone?

Comment: Is there some doubt here that you need Rov to clarify something?

Comment: @DoubleAA true- but while *rov* is usually used to clarify a *safeik* there is precedence to extend *rov* to other areas (see Bach YD 18:16 https://www.sefaria.org/Bach%2C_Yoreh_Deah.18.16.1?lang=bi&with=Tur&lang2=en and other examples https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%93%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%90_%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%9F)

Comment: @alicht I don't understand your example. What else is rov being used for?

Comment: @DoubleAA fair enough- by capital punishment we follow *rov* and that's not a case of *safeik*. If 17 say "kill him" and 6 say "don't"- the Sanhedrin kills the person

Comment: The classic use of Rov to clarify the doubt if he is guilty!

Comment: In הוריות we require רוב of the people transgressing to need a פר העלם דבר.   For a הדס you need רוב of the leaves to be dry for it to be פסול.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, a misconception: rov has no impact on how Chazal choose to commemorate an event. To put is more succinctly: there is no pre-existing sofek when Purim naturally occurs.
A second misconception: the walled cities category is due to the fighting in Shushan, not all walled cities.
Finally, the main miracle took place in Shushan, as well as the most danger coming from there (hence needing two days to deal with the threat). As such it was likely unthinkable to Chazal *not* to commemorate this.

Comment: thanks for the answer and here's an upvote! Do you happen to have a source/ sources for the *shita* you're saying?

Comment: "the most danger coming from there (hence needing two days to deal with the threat)" That's not obvious. The simple read is that was the only place where they could issue a proclamation in time for an extra day. They didn't have cell phones back then

Comment: @DoubleAA indeed, a good point, and the the two days business is based on something I once saw. The ralbag does says this: https://www.sefaria.org/Ralbag_Esther.9.13.1?lang=bi  but he wasn't my original source- that one also pointed out that the death toll Shushan to rest of empire and iirc said the presence of Homons sons was one of the reasons.